# Help with fading in list on page load

Tags: jquery, fade, onload

So I've been trying to fade in a list of  4 links on page load, vertically one after the other with a delay in between using:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     function fadeItem() {
          $('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn(fadeItem);
```

links in list are currently not effected by the above script on page load.

My problem, I think, is that I have each item in the list individually positioned with an absolute value

or,

I already have a script running involving the li classes I'm trying to consecutively fade causing a conflict between the two scripts.

The jQuery script I'm already running with no problems:

```
<script type>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#thumb ul li a').hover(
            function() {
                var currentBigImage = $('#gallery img').attr('src');
                var newBigImage = $(this).attr('src');
                var currentThumbSrc = $(this).attr('rel');
                switchImage(newBigImage, currentBigImage, currentThumbSrc);
            },
            function() {}
        );
    function switchImage(imageHref, currentBigImage, currentThumbSrc) {
            var theBigImage = $('#gallery img');
            if (imageHref != currentBigImage) {
                theBigImage.fadeOut(250, function(){
                    theBigImage.attr('src', imageHref).fadeIn(250);
                    var newImageDesc = $("#thumb ul li a img[src='"+currentThumbSrc+"']").attr('alt');
                    $('p#desc').empty().html(newImageDesc);
                });
            }
        }
});
</script>
```

I'm still getting used to jQuery so the script in question might be totally wrong.  From what I understand, `$(document).ready(function() {` loads items first then carries out the function(s).  If there is a better way of fading in li classes on page load, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What's it currently doing, not fading anything, erroring, fading them all at once, other?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the li classes I'm trying to fade on page load aren't effected by the first script in my post, not fading anything. My guess is a script conflict but I could be wrong.

Comment: @dcd018 - so they remain hidden the entire time?

Comment: They aren't effected at all, like it is being ignored by jQuery?  I'm not exactly sure but they appear on load, however, second script is functioning as it should which is why I assume a scripting conflict exists.  I can post my html if needed.. didn't want to congest the original post.

Comment: @dcd018 - You'll need to `.hide()` those elements first, it doesn't *seem* like that's happening currently, e.g. if you run `$('ul li').hide();` before, does it work properly?

Comment: Ok, i see what my problem was.  With your code, I got the links to hide correctly on load, but the fade in function isn't kicking in e.g. links won't appear.. giving fade to a shot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're defining `fadeItem()` in that document ready, but since you didn't paste the whole thing, I'm not sure you are ever actually **calling** it? Calling `fadeItem()` from the document ready should suffice to kick the process into gear.

It might be easier to just write:

```
// $(fn) is an alias for $(document).ready(fn)
$(function fadeItem() {
   $("ul li:hidden:first").delay(500).fadeIn(fadeItem);
});
```

That way the function is called on document ready, and can still call itself.

Also, considering your response in some of the comments - the [`:hidden` selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector) will only find elements that are `display: none`, or a width and height of 0 (and input hidden, but that doesn't apply to `ul li`.)

You might need to actually HIDE the items before you search for hidden items...

Comment: A named function here is a bad idea, for example most versions of IE will throw an error with your code.

Comment: @Nick Craver - reference? http://jsfiddle.net/gnarf/pLYXF/2/ is a fiddle setup for you to take a nice screenshot of IE throwing an error with my code.

Comment: @Nick Craver - Are you referring to the fact that IE <9 leaks the named expression to the containing scope (when it shouldn't) and other browsers don't?  I just double checked that fiddle on IE 7, 8 (8 in 7 mode) and 9

Comment: @gnarf - Your *particular* example won't throw, named function expressions are a bad idea for a few reasons, but yes at the top of the list is IE's improper handling of them (and the large user base exposed to that), for further reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679657/named-function-expressions-in-ie-part-2 and http://kangax.github.com/nfe/#named-expr

Comment: @Nick Craver - Then is there any particular reason you said 21 minutes before that my code would cause a thrown error in IE?  In fact I find any mention of errors thrown in IE in either of your references.  The NFE used in my example is perfectly safe.  There won't be weird issues with duplication or namespace clashing, unless of course there was another `fadeItem()` function defined in the same scope as the document ready which I consider highly unlikely.  Avoiding the NFE inside the function call would be done by moving it into the higher scope anyway, so I don't see a problem.

Comment: @gnarf - I was thinking it would in IE6, but you're safe back to 5 which is reasonable.  For the other part: "Avoiding the NFE inside the function call would be done by moving it into the higher scope anyway" I completely agree...and that's what's already done in the original code, so why not stay that route to be safe?  There are already other things happening in a `document.ready` event handler here, it's more wasteful to call another.

Comment: @Nick Craver - Sure, whichever way is easier to write or use at the time. I was just pointing out that the incomplete example he pasted had a terser option.  Who knew the guy just forgot to actually hide his items ;)... Now that you are no longer arguing the *incorrect* "named function here is a bad idea" statement, I'm going to go back to actually working on jQuery instead of arguing about it. ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want your function fadeItem() to be executed on document ready, you must also execute it instantly. Have you tried this (why did you pass fadeIitem function as a parameter to fadeIn()? The first parameter should be the duration of the fading):

```
 function fadeItem() {
      $('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn(400);
 }();//execute the function
```

Otherwise don't put the fading inside a function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
          $('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn(400);
```

Comment: [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn) can take a callback function without a duration as well.  He is creating a "recursive" callback chain, as each elements finishes fading in, he wants to find the next element and start it fading in.  Perfectly legal.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments it seems like this is just a misunderstanding, [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) won't have an effect on an *already 100% visible* element, you need to [`.hide()`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) the element first, something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('ul li').hide();
   function fadeItem() {
      $('ul li:hidden:first').delay(500).fadeIn(fadeItem);
```

You *could* do this in CSS, but I recommend against it, since this will let your non-JS users see the list items, instead of having them hidden and *stay* hidden via CSS.

Comment: Thanks, any thoughts as to why they stay hidden?  Ive tried .fadeTo("slow",1) in place of .fadeIn(400) with the same results.

Comment: @dcd018 - Where is the initial call to `fadeItem()`? It's not included in your posted code...also inside `fadeItem()` what does `alert($('ul li:hidden:first').length);` give you?

Comment: I managed to get it working.. assigning a hide() function, hidden search along with a delay in increments for EACH li class worked in both IE and Firefox.  Can't post an answer with revised code for another 5hrs since I'm still a noob lol.