# Javascript: Inconsistency when assigning a named function to a variable (named function expression)

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, cross-browser

Can anyone explain the difference in behaviour between Internet Explorer and Firefox in regards to the below:

```
var myNamespace = (function () {
  var exposed = {};

  exposed.myFunction = function myFunction () {
    return "Works!";
  }

  console.log(myFunction()); 
  // IE: "Works!"
  // Firefox: ReferenceError: myFunction is not defined

  console.log(exposed.myFunction());
  // IE: "Works!"
  // FF: "Works!"

  return exposed;
})();

console.log(myNamespace.myFunction()); 
// IE: "Works!"
// FF: "Works!"
```

In internet explorer this method allows me to call my function from inside my namespace function by using either `myFunction()` or `exposed.myFunction()`.

Outside my namepsace function I can use `myNamespace.myFunction()`

In Firefox, the results are the same with the exception of the bare named function call which does not work.

Should it work? If it shouldn't, then why not?

If it should then is this a known bug?

Comment: This might answer your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553632/detachevent-not-working-with-named-inline-functions, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679657/named-function-expressions-in-ie-part-2.

Comment: tl;dr: No, it should not work, it's a bug in IE.

Comment: OT: Don't assign arbitrary properties to arrays, only use numerical property names. If you want to assign arbitrary properties, use an object instead. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects.

Comment: Agreed. I've changed it to an object, which is was meant to be in the first place.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To prevent false information:

IE has a problem with **named function expressions** which is what you have. The name of the function should only be available **inside** the function. From the [specification](http://es5.github.com/#x13):

> The *Identifier* in a *FunctionExpression* can be referenced from inside the *FunctionExpression*'s *FunctionBody* to allow the function to call itself recursively. However, unlike in a *FunctionDeclaration*, the *Identifier* in a *FunctionExpression* cannot be referenced from and does not affect the scope enclosing the *FunctionExpression*.

where *FunctionExpression* is defined as:

> *FunctionExpression* :
>        `function` *Identifier*<sub>opt</sub> `(` *FormalParameterList*<sub>opt</sub> ) `{` *FunctionBody* `}`

But in IE, instead of making the name only available inside the function, it creates two *different* function objects, one assigned to the variable and the other to the name you gave the function. The following will yield `false` in IE (and throw an error in other browsers):

```
exposed.myFunction === myFunction;
```

It's a known bug and if you have to code for (older versions of) IE, you better avoid named function expressions.

---

Related question:

- [detachEvent not working with named inline functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2553632/detachevent-not-working-with-named-inline-functions)
- [Named Function Expressions in IE, part 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2679657/named-function-expressions-in-ie-part-2)

Comment: Brilliant! This explain perfectly why the code above 'works' in IE and not in Firefox. Of course, the behaviour in Firefox is not what I epxected but it is on spec, which is what matters.

Comment: `console.log(myFunction());`, working for IE, is a call to the local function that according to your specifications, should exist. (FunctionBody, in this context, is the nearest enveloppe of `exposed`, exactly where the bare call is made)

Comment: @Sebas: No, we are talking about the  FunctionExpression's FunctionBody, not the FunctionBody it is defined in. Maybe you haven't seen my update yet. According to the specification, it should **not** exist.

Comment: I understand your point. Maybe I'm interpreting it wrongly, but to me there's a problem here because we're talking about declaring functions and their related scope (in which I agree 100% with your post) when actually there's an overlaying function affectation. See my post: the declaration of the function is definitely outside of the body of `exposed`, even though afterwards, it is affected to it as a property. But maybe I'm misunderstanding the engine.

Comment: @Sebas: To be honest, I cannot follow your last comment. The problem at hand is that IE creates a symbol with the name of the function expression in the scope where the function is defined, and this is wrong. Everything else is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2):

This:

```
exposed.myFunction = function myFunction () {
    return "Works!";
}
```

is useless (- correcting myself: it is NOT incorrect - ) and apparently buggy (see Felix's post). If you wish to declare a function part of `exposed` you don't need to name it:

```
exposed.myFunction = function() {
    return "Works!";
}
```

However, if you want to declare a local function **and then** also affect it to your array `exposed`, you can do:

```
function myFunction () {
    return "Works!";
}

exposed.myFunction = myFunction;
```

which would, in this case, successfully validate `(exposed.myFunction === myFunction) === true;`

Also, please note that your call to `console.log(myNamespace.myFunction());` is identical to your call to `console.log(exposed.myFunction());` since `myNamespace` is actually the object `exposed`.

Comment: It is **NOT** incorrect. It's a named function expression and perfectly valid JavaScript.

Comment: then firefox should allow the execution of the `console.log(myFunction());`, otherwise there's an inconsistency.

Comment: No, IE should properly implement JavaScript.

Comment: I mean, if you say the first expression is correct, then it means the declaration of the bare `myFunction` should be taken in consideration as of the current context, hence be valid called as is.

Comment: But that's not how function expressions are defined. See my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Also, By defining

```
exposed.myFunction = function() {}
```

You are setting `exposed`'s *property* to be `myFunction`.

And it is not available in the `myNamespace` scope.

By defining

```
exposed.myFunction = function myFunction() {}
```

The function is created in the scope of `myNamespace`, and then referenced as a property of `exposed`.