# Named function expression

Tags: javascript

I'm assigning a named function expression to a property of an object:

```
var foo = {};

foo.bar = function bar(){
    console.log('bar');
};
```

- `foo.bar()` => *bar*
- `bar()` => *ReferenceError: bar is not defined*

**Why can't I call `bar()` directly, why isn't it defined?**

I know that I can simply chain the assignment like `var bar = foo.bar = function(){}`, so I'm not looking for a work-around or other solution, I'm only interested in *why* it doesn't work.

I've tested in Chrome console and Node.JS.

Comment: `bar()` actually means `window.bar()` which is not defined within `window` namespace. Instead it is defined in `foo` namespace.

Comment: See also [Javascript: Inconsistency when assigning a named function to a variable (named function expression)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14732107/javascript-inconsistency-when-assigning-a-named-function-to-a-variable-named-f)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Named function expressions are simply not supposed to work that way. The function name is only visible *inside* the function, not outside.

A function instantiation expression that happens to have a name is not the same thing as a function declaration statement. Those are two distinct syntactic (and semantic) entities in the language.